# method for adding objects in array of object

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

I'm working on a class called Library. This class has two attributes: `books[]` an array of type `Book` and `nbrBooks` of type `int`.

I'm looking to build a method called `addBook` with a book parameter of type `Book` which returns true if the book was added. And returns false if the parameter `book` was null. So far I have something like this:

```
public boolean addBook(Book book) throws LivreInvalideException {
    boolean a = true;
    getNbrBooks();
    if (book == null) {
        a = false;
        throw new LivreInvalideException();
    }   
    books [nbrBooks] = book;
    return a;
}
```

My professor gave us a class `Test` to check if our code is working and it doesn't seem to work. I'm wondering why...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you post the test code that is failing?

Comment: What do you mean `doesnt seem to work`? How are we supposed to know how your unit tests are supposed to work

Comment: Don't forget to add one to `nbrBooks` when the book is added successfully.

Comment: can you edit your question to show what `getNbrBooks()` does

Comment: if ***getNbrBooks()*** is actually a getter where is the value going to???

Comment: nbrBooks is not declared in the code you show. Also, what happens if books is dimensioned n, and you try to add n+1 books? Your professor should not be telling you to use an array; you should be using an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean addBook(Book book){
   if( book == null) {
   return false;}

   books[nbrBooks] = book; 
   nbrBooks++;
   return true;}
```

this is super simple but I hope it helps a bit!